# Condition block current day datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I can not block the current day if the time of day is greater than 16 in my condition...

I would like to block the current day if the time of day is greater than 16. Thank you for your help

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#datepicker").datepicker().datepicker('setDate', new Date());

            var d = new Date();
            var n = d.getHours();


            if (n>16) {
                var disableddates = ["14-01-2017", "15-01-2017"];
            }


            function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
                return [disableddates.indexOf(string) == -1];
            }


            $( function() {
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
                $.datepicker.regional['fr'] = {
                    closeText: 'Fermer',
                    prevText: 'Précédent',
                    nextText: 'Suivant',
                    currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
                    monthNames: ['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin','Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'],
                    monthNamesShort: ['Janv.','Févr.','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin','Juil.','Août','Sept.','Oct.','Nov.','Déc.'],
                    dayNames: ['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'],
                    dayNamesShort: ['Dim.','Lun.','Mar.','Mer.','Jeu.','Ven.','Sam.'],
                    dayNamesMin: ['D','L','M','M','J','V','S'],
                    weekHeader: 'Sem.',
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                    firstDay: 1,
                    isRTL: false,
                    showMonthAfterYear: false,
                    beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates,
                    minDate: 0,
                    yearSuffix: ''},
                    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Can you post the rest of the code please?

Comment: You have an array with one item, an empty string, how is that going to match a string that contains a date ?

Comment: What does this have to do with `JSON.stringify`? Also, you're comparing dates with two-digit years (`formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date)`) with dates that have four digits (`"14-01-2017"`)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set the `minDate` value on the fly with `n > 16 ? 1 : 0`

Working code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#datepicker").datepicker().datepicker('setDate', new Date());

  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getHours();

  $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    $.datepicker.regional['fr'] = {
        closeText: 'Fermer',
        prevText: 'Précédent',
        nextText: 'Suivant',
        currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
        monthNames: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Janv.', 'Févr.', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juil.', 'Août', 'Sept.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Déc.'],
        dayNames: ['Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dim.', 'Lun.', 'Mar.', 'Mer.', 'Jeu.', 'Ven.', 'Sam.'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D', 'L', 'M', 'M', 'J', 'V', 'S'],
        weekHeader: 'Sem.',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        minDate: n > 16 ? 1 : 0,
        yearSuffix: ''
      },
      $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Date:
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
  </p>


</body>

</html>
```